# Disallow subsequent h/j/k/l

Tags: vim

I want to force myself to not press `jjjjj` and rather use `5j` instead. I'm looking for a solution that forbids / disables that kind of subsequent motion usage.

For initially practicing `h/j/k/l` instead of arrows I used

```
nnoremap <Left> :echoe "Use h"<CR>
nnoremap <Right> :echoe "Use l"<CR>
nnoremap <Up> :echoe "Use k"<CR>
nnoremap <Down> :echoe "Use j"<CR>
```

I tried to do something similar like

```
nnoremap jj :echoe "Use xj"<CR>
nnoremap ll :echoe "Use xl"<CR>
nnoremap kk :echoe "Use xk"<CR>
nnoremap hh :echoe "Use xh"<CR>
```

But this results in that even jumping with `5j` needs to wait for the vim timeout.

Comment: Bad idea. If reading `:help navigation` is not enough to make you forget both the arrows *and* `hjkl` you should consider switching to another, simpler, editor.

Comment: @romainl Maybe I explained myself wrong. I am familiar with most of vims motions and use it on a daily base as my main editor for over a year now. Though since the beginning I used `hjkl` as navigation instead of jumping. I am now trying to retrain my brain to jump instead of hammer `hjkl`

Comment: I consider this question should be taken in a generalized nature. An academic perspective. Like how to set ttimeoutlen or its alternatives for a single command or a group. For example how to use different timeout for leaderkey?

Comment: Might want to have a look at [vim-hardtime](https://github.com/takac/vim-hardtime)

Comment: @Marth this seems to be exactly what I was searching for. I was hoping for a more simple solution inside .vimrc but nevertheless, if you post this as an answer I'm happy to accept it until something else comes up.

Comment: @dvcrn, please give a look at my solution, which might like as well

Answer (score 2):

I've checked `vim-hardtime`, but it also prevents me from doing things like <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> within the timeout, which I would hardly call a bad habit, but rather a sudden change of mind while navigating.

The following might be a starting point (to be put in your `.vimrc` file) from which you can develop your own plugin:

```
nno <silent> j :<C-U>execute "call Restrictedj(" . v:count . ")"<CR>
let g:moved1 = v:false
fu! Restrictedj(count)
  if a:count > 1
    exe line('.') + a:count
    let g:moved1 = v:false
  else
    if !g:moved1
      exe line('.') + 1
    else
      echoe 'Use xj'
    end
    let g:moved1 = v:true
  end
endf
```

Such a code will make <kbd>j</kbd> (without count) error from the second use of it on.

The main fault is that you can only reactivate it by pressing <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, or more, and not by pressing any other key (which would be desirable).

In principle the function can be modified in such a way that pressing each one of the four <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> reactivates the remaining three. However I think that the ideal is that each of <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> should be reactivated by any action other than pressing that key again.

Answer (score 1):

The `timeout` is unavoidable by definition, but you could at least reduce the timeout by setting `timeoutlen`. It defaults to `1000`, which is quite long. You could probably get away with lowering it to `500`, especially seeing as you are planning on using this only temporarily as a training aid.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I ended up removing the habit just the way I learned Vim in the first place: I forced myself for a hour or two just moving around with <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> prepended by numbers.

---

The following is a more self-contained solution: one function and four mappings for <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>.

There is no timer, but the only way to "reactivate" each of the four keys is using it with an explicit count or using one of the three other keys.

```
fu! NoRepHJKL(count, key, selfCall)
  if !exists('g:can_use')
    let g:can_use = { 'h': v:true, 'j': v:true, 'k': v:true, 'l': v:true }
  endif
  if a:count > 0
    execute "normal! " . a:key
    call NoRepHJKL(a:count - 1, a:key, v:true)
  else
    if a:selfCall || g:can_use[a:key]
      let g:can_use.h = v:true
      let g:can_use.j = v:true
      let g:can_use.k = v:true
      let g:can_use.l = v:true
    endif
    if !a:selfCall && g:can_use[a:key]
      execute "normal! " . a:key
      let g:can_use[a:key] = v:false
    endif
  endif
endf
nn <silent> h :<C-U>call NoRepHJKL(v:count, 'h', v:false)<CR>
nn <silent> j :<C-U>call NoRepHJKL(v:count, 'j', v:false)<CR>
nn <silent> k :<C-U>call NoRepHJKL(v:count, 'k', v:false)<CR>
nn <silent> l :<C-U>call NoRepHJKL(v:count, 'l', v:false)<CR>
```

The function

- defines a global boolean dictionary for the four keys (only the first time it's called) which contains whether each of the four key can be used;
- if the `a:count` passed to it is positive (this includes `1`), it uses the key (given through the argument `a:key`) in `normal` mode and calls itself recursively, with a reduced `a:count` argument, and with the information that the it is `a:selfCall`ing.
- if the `a:count` is zero

  - it will make all four keys available for the next use only if it reached zero by recursion or (if not) if the `a:key` is not been overused;
  - if it is not a self call, but the `a:key` is not been overused, then it uses it in `normal` mode and makes it unavailable for the next use.